# fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

Tags: debian-wheezy, fuse, gcsfuse

I am running an instance on gcloud compute engine. I need to mount a Google storage bucket (which belongs to a different project) to my instance. The instance runs on Debian Wheezy. I have installed gcc, fuse, gcsfuse. But when I tried to mount the bucket:

*$ gcsfuse bucket-name /mnt/bucket-name*

I got the error:
**stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first**

Tried "modprobe fuse", I got error:
**-bash: modprobe: command not found**

Anyone knows what the problem might be, or anyone has encountered the same issue? Any thoughts, comments, help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is using **Cloud Run** on Google Cloud Platform, second generation of execution environment should be used.

```
gcloud beta run deploy filesystem-app  --source . \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --service-account fs-identity \
    --update-env-vars BUCKET=[YOUR_BUCKET] \
    --region=europe-north1 \
    --execution-environment gen2
```

Flag `--execution-environment gen2` it vital based on [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments#choose):

```
You should use second generation if any of the following apply to your Cloud Run service:
  - Your service needs to use a network file system, which is only supported by second generation.
  - ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue with an upgrade to Jessie and then installed gcsfuse following the instructions here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md

Comment: That is actually a poor suggestion to a simple problem of finding a system command.

Answer (score 1):

To locate a command on your system, you can use `whereis` which will search all the common locations to give you the full path.

```
whereis modprobe
```

.. on my system outputs:

> modprobe: /sbin/modprobe /etc/modprobe.d /etc/modprobe.conf /lib/modprobe.d /usr/share/man/man8/modprobe.8.bz2

In this case, and probably yours, you would then know to call it as `/sbin/modprobe fuse`.

Comment: Have tried that, but it wasn't there.